# Silverlight SDK DataGrid not always fire MouseLeftButtonUp event?

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, mouseevent

Why does the `DataGrid` not always fire the `MouseLeftButtonUp` event?

I try to implement a single click behaviour on `DataGridTextColumn` and bind to this event.

```
dataGrid.MouseLeftButtonUp += OnDataGridMouseLeftButtonUp;
```

In the handler I call `BeginEdit()` and set focus on the `TextBox` element. It works when I get the event, but it is not always fired? Does anyone know how to fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using AddHandler instead.

```
  dataGrid.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseLeftButtonUpEvent,
      new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnMouseLeftButtonUp), true)
```

...

```
private void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  // etc...
}
```